# What does Hibernate Query.executeUpdate do?

Tags: java, jquery, database, hibernate, orm

I deleted the record by using following code :

```
Query query = session.createQuery("delete from Emp where id=100");  
query.executeUpdate();
```

What happens if I do not write `query.executeUpdate()`?

Comment: Nothing happens. You create a query and don't execute it.

Comment: What happens if you try it?

Comment: I tried it. Record has been deleted without being used query.executeUpdate();

Answer (score 1):

If you don't call `query.executeUpdate()` then you just have a `Query` object on the Heap, waiting to be garbage collected when it's no longer referenced.

Like the method name implies, the `executeUpdate` is what makes the `Query` to be run against the database.

Comment: That's just impossible.